# Dynamic template for a dashboard in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have to create a dashboard with Angular 7 where the layout structure and the components to show are defined by the user.
Let's say that there are three components (but they could be much more): chartA, chartB, chartC and two users.

During app initialization in the AppService, just after the user login, a function create the variable "userTemplate" with the layout based on the preferences of the user.

For the user1 the userTemplate will be:

```
<div class="flexHorizontal">
    <app-chartA></app-chartA>
    <app-chartB></app-chartB>
</div>
```

Instead for the user2 will be:

```
<div class="flexVertical">
    <app-chartA></app-chartA>
    <div class="flexHorizontal">
        <app-chartB></app-chartB>
        <app-chartC></app-chartC>
    </div>
</div>
```

If in the app.component.ts would be possible to assign this variable to the template property, the problem would be solved very easily. But it isn't possible. I get "Cannot read property 'userTemplate' of undefined".

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './services/app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: this.userTemplate,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Dashboard';
  userTemplate: string;

  constructor (private app: AppService ){
    this.userTemplate=app.config.template;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Component(...)` is a decorator of the class `AppComponent` it is defined before the instantiation of the class, thus `this.userTemplate` doesn't exist at that time, but also it isn't in the variable scope, thus your error. There is no `this` at the scope outside of the `AppComponent` class.

The following resource should help you along with dynamic templates: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I already saw the dynamic component loader, but it seems to me that it doesn't allow the flexibility that I need to setup the page layout.